# Button laid out using layout_toLeftOf in a RelativeLayout does not show up

Tags: java, android, layout

I am trying to layout a Button to the left of a TextView that is centered on the screen. My layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

 <TextView  
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="foo"
     android:id="@+id/center"
     />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Left button"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Unfortunately, the button just does not appear. I get the following result: [image]

As you see, the button doesn't show up. It works if I use layout_toRightOf, then the button appears to the right of the TextView, just as expected.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have not provided any rules for positioning the `TextView`. If you want the `TextView` centered, say so (e.g., `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`)
2. You have not provided any rules for vertically positioning the `Button`.
3. Use `hierarchyviewer` to inspect your layout to figure out where things are being positioned.

Comment: Your post made me realize that I know hardly anything about layout on Android. Thanks for the helpful pointers.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I realize this was answered ages ago, but it is amazing how seldom this answer is given and how hard it is to find. Thank you so much! Saved me a day of reworking junk into LinearLayouts.

Comment: @WesWinn: This question is so old, I had forgotten that the emulator ever looked like it did in the screenshot... :-) Glad to hear it helped, though!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Left button">
</Button>
<TextView  
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="foo"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button"
     android:id="@+id/center">
</TextView>
```

Comment: Rpond, thanks for your response. If I follow your suggestion, the TextView is not centered on the screen any more. Any ideas how to ensure that the TextView is centered? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pad your text to move it where you want...